# Gomock not working for sending data to cockroach DB

Tags: unit-testing, go, gomock

I am writing a unit test for a function which calls a goroutine to send data to cockroach db. I am trying to mock the call to cockroach db which doesn't seem to work.The test case results in time out in the exact same manner as it would have if there was no mocking done for sendBatch to cockroach db.

here are the functions:

```
func DrainQueue() {
    for range time.Tick(time.Second * time.Duration(1)) {
        if q.Length() > 0 {
            var queuedItems []interface{}

            // Read the queue up to the size specified.
            for qlen := 0; qlen < QueueSize && q.Length() > 0; qlen++ {
                itemFromQueue := q.Pop()

                queuedItems = append(queuedItems, itemFromQueue)
            }

            logging.Debug("Sending to cockroachDB...")

            go SendToCockRoachDB(queuedItems...)
            queuedItems = nil
        }
    }
}

func SendToCockRoachDB(toSend ...interface{}) ([][][]byte, int64, error) {
    var nor int64
    var qErr error
    var rows pgx.Rows
    var results = make([][][]byte, 0)

    batch := &pgx.Batch{}
    for _, item := range toSend {
        qs := item.(*QueryStruct)

        batch.Queue(qs.Query, qs.Items...)
    }

    // Send to cockroachDB
    br := dbConn.dbpool.SendBatch(dbConn.ctx, batch)
    defer br.Close()

    rows, qErr = br.Query()

    if qErr != nil {
        return nil, 0, qErr
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        results = append(results, rows.RawValues())
    }

    nor += rows.CommandTag().RowsAffected()

    if nor > 0 {
        logging.Log.Printf("Inserted: %d rows", nor)
    }
    return results, nor, qErr
}
```

The test function I have created works like this:

```
func TestDrainQueue(t *testing.T) {

    var results = make([][][]byte, 0)
    var nor int64 = 0
    
    controller := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer controller.Finish()

    mockSendBatch := Mocks.NewMockValues(controller)
    mockSendBatch.EXPECT().SendToCockRoachDB(mockSendBatch).Return(results, nor, nil)

    DrainQueue()
}
```

I have created a mock function using gomock for SendToCockRoachDB and have called it in the unit test

Comment: It looks like you aren't passing `mockSendBatch` into your code under test at all. You have to swap the real database for your mock object in the test by using an interface.

Comment: Is it possible to mock a fun without any interface?

Comment: It is possible, some libraries exist that try to do monkey patching, but they aren't portable.

Comment: Can you name any?

Comment: There is github.com/bouk/monkey but in my opinion you are better off structuring your code in concise packages with well defined interfaces and using mock objects, you can do that in the standard library if you like.

Comment: Yes..I should use unterfaces. Thanks for the effort!